# How to update scope variable value in view after http call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, http, angularjs-scope

I am making my first project using **Angularjs 1.4.3**.

In my controller I am making a **http** request, in the **success** method of this http request I am updating a scope variable. In http call I am getting the latest values but in the view side its not updating the values.

[**Plunker Link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSnGQdXFB3lQz9dtmg5o?p=preview)   (@rupesh_padhye thanks). (Since it is calling the servlet action, so no data will be shown in **Plunker**)

```
app.controller('measuresCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$http', function($scope, $modal, $http) {



    $scope.groups = []
        $scope.loadAllMeasure = function() {
            $http.get("fetchAllMeasure")
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log("Before insert");
                console.log($scope.groups);

                $scope.groups = data.measures;

                console.log("After insert");
                console.log($scope.groups);
            })
            .error(function() {
            });
        };

        $scope.loadAllMeasure();

$scope.submit = function (form) {
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'saveMeasure',
        data: {
               id: form.id,
               name: form.name,
               description: form.description
              },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.loadAllMeasure();
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   });
 }
```

})

And whenever I am performing any CRUD operation on measures I am calling a method `$scope.loadAllMeasure();`. But its not updating the values in the view (jsp) page.

I have tried **$scope.$apply** method but I am getting `Error: $digest already in progress`.

When I printed the value for **$scope.groups** using **console.log** inside **success** method, then its showing the latest values.

In my view (jsp) page I am just using **ng-repeat** function to show all the records in table format.

**Code for my view page (minimal code) -**

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:'name'">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{group.id}}" class="ui-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div>{{ group.description}}</div>
    <div>   
            <div class="fa fa-pencil button" data="{{group.id}}" id="{{::elementId}}" ng-click="showEditForm(group.id, $event)"></div>
            <div class="fa fa-trash button" data="{{group.id}}" ng-click="deleteGroup(group.id)"></div>
            <div class="fa fa-clone button" data="{{group.id}}" id="{{::elementId}}" ng-click="showCloneForm(group.id, $event)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Values in console.log are**

```
Before insert
Object { id=1,  description="Measure Description1",  name="Demo"}]
```

And

```
After Insert
 [Object { id=1,  description="Measure Description1",  name="Demo"}, Object { id=2,  description="Description2",  name="Demo2"}]
```

**How to update scope variable value in view after http call?**

Comment: You don't need to update scope variable, `$http`  does it automatically

Comment: Then why its showing old values in view?

Comment: Can you post the view?

Comment: You need to use ng-model="id", not data="{{group.id}}"

Comment: **data="{{group.id}}"** works with no issue, and I am not showing **id** to user.

Comment: can you please show us the values you logged to the console? Is `data.measures` an array and in the correct format as you are expecting it?

Comment: Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/P61Fvb?p=preview .I tried to replicate your code and its works with out any issue

Comment: @rupesh_padhye Thanks for the plunker, you are using static data so there are no issues, my values are coming from servlet, so its not syncing with view

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I have added the values I am getting in console.log, its an array

Comment: Do you have any other controllers in play on this HTML? Are there any other controllers around the mentioned HTML?

Comment: No, I have multiple view pages each having separate controllers.

Comment: @Deepu If you remove the `filter` does your code work?

Comment: From where to remove `filter`?

Comment: @Deepu From your html. The `orderBy` part

Comment: You mean `orderBy:'name'`??

Comment: @Deepu Yes the `orderby:name`

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I tried to remove `orderBy:'name'`, still same issue except the ordering is changed.

Comment: @Deepu please see my answer

Comment: Ok @TjaartvanderWalt I will try your solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant see anything wrong with your example code.

I have created a JSFiddle to try and help you.

The server call has been replaced by a setTimeout function that returns a promise.

Please see JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sjwkbzxa/

Please see example below:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestController as vm">
    <button data-ng-click="loadAllMeasure()">Load List from Server</button>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:'name'">
            <span>{{group.description}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
angular.module('application',[]).controller("TestController", ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q){    
    $scope.groups = [{ id:1,  description:"Initial List",  name:"Demo"}];

    $scope.loadAllMeasure = function(){
       loadData().then(function(data){
         $scope.groups = data;
       });
     };

    function loadData(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){
            var data = [{ id:1,  description:"Measure Description1",  name:"Demo"}, { id:2,  description:"Description2",  name:"Demo2"}];
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, 3000);
       return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Maybe you are missing something on your side that we cant see?

Comment: Thanks,
I am actually not able to demonstrate it in fiddle, since my data is coming from database through servlet response. With static data as you mentioned is working fine, but with dynamic data its not working. I can see the updated values in database, console.log but not in View :(

Comment: @Deepu If it does not work with data from the server it means the data you are getting from the server is not in the correct format. If you use a `setTimeout` or use data from a API makes no different.

Comment: Data is in correct format, if I refresh the page then I am getting all updated data. Because when controller loads I am calling `$scope.loadAllMeasure` method, but even after the save measure I have called the same method, then it doesnt update the list. But when I refresh the page it displays all data.

Comment: Can you add the code you mention in "Because when controller loads I am calling `$scope.loadAllMeasure` method"

Comment: Yes its immediately after declaration of `$scope.loadAllMeasure`, updated in question.

Comment: When do you call the `loadAllMeasure` function? After the save? Can you please add the save code?

Comment: Yes I have updated the question with save Measure code. Submit method is there

Comment: @Deepu If you update your code `$scope.groups = data.measures;` to be `$scope.groups = someStaticArray;` does your view update?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
Strange! with static data also its not updating the view. I have added static array if `$scope.groups.length > 0` in `success` method of `http` call. I think the view is getting rendered before completing `http` call.

Comment: @Deepu is your view in a directive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96759/discussion-between-deepu-and-tjaart-van-der-walt).

Answer (score 7):

After assigning the new data to a $scope variable call:

$scope.$digest();

This will update the current scopes values

reference here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. I was updating a $scope variable into a event handler function (.on( ) of socket.io) but the variable value just changed in the view when the function was called for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to answer this, but here are my 2 cents:

A simple assignment of the server data (response.data) to a $scope object didnt seem to work for me

```
$scope.something = response.data //didn't work
```

So, I returned a promise object from the service into the controller and then use

```
angular.copy(response.data,$scope.something)
```

to copy the values returned from the server. You could also pass the $scope.something to the service as a parameter to the function and have angular.copy in the service function as well, but i don't know if it's a good practise to do that.

Comment: $http is async call, if you get delay in response then in angular.copy will have different value than the response value. Anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear... I use angular.copy(source,dest) in the 'then' clause of the promise returned by the $http call. So far thankfully I've not seen the problem you've reported, but will keep an eye. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.loadAllMeasure = function() {
     CalltoServer();
 };

 CalltoServer = function() {
    return $http.get("fetchAllMeasure")
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.groups = data.measures;
    })
    .error(function() {
    });
 }
```

try this , the success will be after 2 or 3 seconds so i guess inside the event it takes rist to bind

Comment: No luck with this one also :(

Comment: ng-controller="measuresCtrl" added ?  or controller declared in routing ?  if not it wont work for some scenario , i didnt find any error on your code

Comment: My controller is **measuresCtrl** and **fetchAllMeasure** is action method from servlet.

Comment: Whats the difference by adding extra method?

Comment: .success(function(data) {
        //Here it will come after the success 
})  the $http request is in another angular event , that makes it to difficulties in binding

Answer (score 0):

Hey I also faced the same issue and if anyone is still looking, it is caused by change in the $scope variable inside the $http. I think a new $scope is being created inside the success function(some prototypical inheritance stuff).
So make a copy of the variable $scope, something like

```
var s = $scope;
```

and then change

```
s.groups = someData;
```

Your code:

```
app.controller('measuresCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$http', function($scope, $modal, $http) {


var s = $scope;
$scope.groups = []
    $scope.loadAllMeasure = function() {
        $http.get("fetchAllMeasure")
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("Before insert");
            console.log($scope.groups);

            s.groups = data.measures;

            console.log("After insert");
            console.log($scope.groups);
        })
        .error(function() {
        });
    };

    $scope.loadAllMeasure();

$scope.submit = function (form) {
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'saveMeasure',
    data: {
           id: form.id,
           name: form.name,
           description: form.description
          },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.loadAllMeasure();
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
}
})
```