# I want to update angular js varibale after ajax response

Tags: php, html, angularjs, ajax

```
        $scope.dis = 0;
        $scope.getDiscount = function (value) {
            $http.post('Pestcontrol/offer',{"code_id":value,}).then(function(response) {
                // Stored the returned data into scope
                $scope.dis = response.data.result;
                
                
                console.log($scope.dis); //print 10 in console
                
               
            });
        };
```

**{{dis}} = 0 initial result in html**
****I want print {{dis}} = 10 or any digit in html after post response value ****
my json response value is

code_id:"STIFF"

status:"ok"

result:"10"

Comment: This should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017376/how-to-update-scope-variable-value-in-view-after-http-call/41658187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="text-left " id="discode" >Percentage({{ ofdis = dis?dis:0}})</span> 
<input type="hidden" name="total_discount" value="{{ofdis}}">
```

**note: ofdis is not updated in ng-init="myVariable='value'; "**

simply use update cdn of Angular js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```